# Can't debug protractor in Webstorm (it just hangs)

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, protractor

I've got an Angular project that I've written a protractor test against, and can't seem to get debugging to work in Webstorm.  When I click the `Run` for my Prototype configuration, it tests successfully.  But if I try the `Debug` button, I get something in the Variables window along the lines of:

```
--!  Connected to 127.0.0.1:52686
```

But it just hangs there - no further processing, and no browser window launched.  Is there something I need to configure to get this working?

Comment: Which version of Protractor are you using? There are opened issues about [debugging with v 0.19.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/552) and [in Webstorm](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/363).

Comment: I am using v0.19.0.  Thanks, I'll look at the issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a Protractor issue, which should be fixed now:

> "Fix is in - should be out next release. Thanks for your patience, everyone." - @juliemr

from [GitHub issue #552](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/552)

**EDIT:** Released in 0.20.0 version! (0.20.1 for Windows users). See [Protractor changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0200).

Answer (score 1):

Try watching this video and let me know if it works.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLMyI7QKcwg

Update: this is a bug in 19 / 20.1
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/603

Try using an older version until it gets resolved.

Comment: no I can't (Win7) npm list bellow
jasmine-reporters@0.4.0
protractor@0.20.1