# Intellij Idea hangs when debugging protractor

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, protractor, webstorm

I have problem similar to one mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082195/cant-debug-protractor-in-webstorm-it-just-hangs).

I'm trying to debug protractor tests in IntelliJ Idea. After I set configuration for Node.js and press *Run* all tests run properly, but after clicking *Debug*, I see only:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk=65500 --nolazy --debug node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js protractor.conf.js
debugger listening on port 65500
[launcher] Running 2 instances of WebDriver
```

And that's it, no browser windows are opened, and in process explorer only Node process is created.

From what I read `--debug-brk` option hangs execution on first line - but in Idea debugger it looks like application is running, not hanging on breakpoint.

Used software versions:

- Intellij Idea  14.0.2 with NodeJs plugin v 139.491
- Node.js v0.10.35
- protractor v 1.6.0

Comment: may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840623/how-to-debug-node-js-child-forked-process: such problems usually occur if the forked child process uses the same debug port as a parent process - as a result the forked process is suspended and the application 'stalls'.

Comment: please try Node 0.11.* - does the issue persist?

Comment: Tried v0.11.14 - same problem occurred at first. And it looked like the issue you linked could be the problem - as there were 2 child processes created with same debug port as parent process. So I disabled one of WebDrivers from debug configuration and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Debugging_Protractor_from_WebStorm_Intellij/

And try to run only "1 instance" when you're debugging.