# executing Intellij ide run configuration outside of the ide UI thread

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, gulp, run-configuration

I'm building a site using node and gulp, the web server starts with a gulp task, that in addition to starting it, also bundles js and css files, and watches for changes.

The issue is, when the gulp task is doing heavy processing, the whole ide UI freezes until the intensive process is finished.

The issue doesn't occur when I issue the task from terminal, so **I assume** that the run configuration runs on the UI thread of the ide (I also suspect it becuase moving files in the project navigator freezes the UI as well, while moving files outside of the ide is much much faster).

My question is wheter it's possible to force the run configuration to run on a seperate thread other then the UI thread?

Not sure if it's helping, but I've attached a screenshot of my current configuration:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct, it doesn't run in the same thread. It even doesn't run in the same process. You should report a [performance problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235) [to support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij Idea hangs when debugging protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968260/intellij-idea-hangs-when-debugging-protractor)